# Spring Jpa Data Repository save (update) with LinkedEntity for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There are 2 entities (lets say Rule and Label) with many-to-many relationship using linked entity
[as per hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional-with-link-entity.)

**Rule enity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "name")
public class Rule implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NaturalId
@NotBlank
@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String content;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<RuleLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

**Label entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
public class Label implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "label", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<RuleLabel> rules = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

**Link entity:**

```
@Entity
public class RuleLabel implements Serializable {

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Rule rule;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Label label;
...
```

**Repositories:**

```
@Repository
public interface LabelRepository extends JpaRepository<Label, Long>
...
@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Rule, Long>
...
```

Creating new entity via **RuleRepository.save(Rule)** works fine, but when I'm trying to update existing entity (the same method **RuleRepository.save(Rule)**, but entity to be saved contains **id** field) it leads to infinite loop of **Hibernate: select...** queries:

```
Hibernate: select rule0_.id as id1_7_1_, rule0_.is_active as is_activ2_7_1_, rule0_.content as content3_7_1_, rule0_.is_deleted as is_delet4_7_1_, rule0_.import_section as import_s5_7_1_, rule0_.name as name6_7_1_, rule0_.rule_configuration as rule_con7_7_1_, labels1_.rule_id as rule_id1_8_3_, labels1_.label_id as label_id2_8_3_, labels1_.rule_id as rule_id1_8_0_, labels1_.label_id as label_id2_8_0_ from rule rule0_ left outer join rule_label labels1_ on rule0_.id=labels1_.rule_id where rule0_.id=?
```

and StackOverflowError as a result

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.getInstance(ServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
...
```

(LabelRepository acts in the same manner)

How it can be fixed?

**Update:**
After changing fetch strategy to Lazy

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Rule rule;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Label label;
```

infinite loop problem has gone, but new one has appeared - related entities are not being populated and when Hibernate is trying to insert values into link table

```
Hibernate: insert into rule_label (rule_id, label_id) values (?, ?)
```

we get

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'rule_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: It would take too long time, for you to paste code for these 2 entities right?...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Added code snippets, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a toString or something that's printing out the recursive relationship, the List of RuleLabel, and the Label?

Comment: When you ask about a specific piece of code causing a specific exception, post that code, and post the exception stack trace. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: Just a guess: Remove your toString() method if you override it.

Comment: I did't override toString, but overrode equals and hashcode according to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html

Comment: Btw if you just wanted a simple ManyToMany bridge relation then why didnt you just use `@ManyToMany` annotation?

Comment: I want to be able to update from both Rule and Label sides, and @ManyToMany allows to update only from owner side. Correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: The cascade should update the ManyToMany relationship from the Rule and Label sides, shouldn't it?

Comment: For me updates from owner side and does not from inverse side.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, well I've always used an `EmbeddableId` for link entities with JPA. I haven't tried the hibernate example you refer to in terms of using cascade to do the work for me. It could be interesting but there are some differences between pure JPA and Spring Data Repositories. By using an `EmbeddableId` you can create a separate spring repository for the link entity. Then you manage the relationships yourself. If you don't want to do that then you should use a `ManyToMany` annotation, but the link entity allows you to create link entity attributes, not shown here. This code will work for you and get you to point B and you can experiment from there:

```
@Entity
public class Label {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ruleLabelId.labelId")
    private List<RuleLabel> rules = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
public class Rule {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ruleLabelId.ruleId")
    private List<RuleLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
public class RuleLabel {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RuleLabelId ruleLabelId;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class RuleLabelId implements Serializable {
    private Long ruleId;
    private Long labelId;

public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Rule, Long> {
    @Query("from Rule r left join fetch r.labels where r.id = :id")
    public Rule getWithLabels(@Param("id") Long id);
}

public interface RuleLabelRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleLabel, RuleLabelId> {}
```

and to use it:

```
Rule rule = new Rule();
Label label = new Label();

ruleRepo.save(rule);
labelRepo.save(label);

RuleLabel ruleLabel = new RuleLabel();
RuleLabelId ruleLabelId = new RuleLabelId();
ruleLabelId.setRuleId(rule.getId());
ruleLabelId.setLabelId(label.getId());
ruleLabel.setRuleLabelId(ruleLabelId);

ruleLabelRepo.save(ruleLabel);

rule = ruleRepo.getWithLabels(1L);
System.out.println(rule + Arrays.toString(rule.getLabels().toArray()));
```

Comment: It's strange that just to make consistent behavior through save and update we need to make such drastic changes and manage link entity manually.
Anyway - thank you a lot, your solution works fine!

Answer (score -1):

Yes because its what you are telling hibernate to do.

By default, all `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` associations are **EAGER** loaded, so when it querying `Rule` then its also querying `RuleLabel` and then inside there is `Rule` again which is causing infinite `select` queries. It's better to have them **LAZY** loaded.

You can do field lazy load like this `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

This is what [JPA 2.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) say about defaults:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

A good [read](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading) on Lazy and Eager loading

Comment: By default they are LAZY loaded. You can have them load lazy with @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) but that would be redundant wouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you, setting @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) helps to avoid infinite loop, but it causes another issue - related entities is not being populated and I've got 'Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'rule_id' cannot be null'

Comment: @K.Nicholas In Hibernate by default all are LAZY loaded but in JPA ManyToOne and OneToOne is EAGER loaded

Comment: @DmitryTkachev update your question with new exception and your query code

Comment: Okay, but the association from Rule to RuleLabel is OnetoMany which is LAZY so why should it query RuleLabel when you update Rule? OP is updating RuleLabel, which updates Rule, but why should it go back to RuleLabel at that point? OP should take out the JSON stuff first and see what happens.

Comment: @K.Nicholas yes you are right this might be a problem too that's why I asked him to put the update query code to get the better idea.

Comment: Agree, but it works fine on create entity - e.g. I just save Rule with some Label inside - and new record is persisted into link table. And I would like to have the same behavior for update as well.

Comment: @DmitryTkachev `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are two separate things. It doesn't mean if your code works on Insert it will also work on Update. Make sure you are setting `id` in the object before doing update query.

Comment: @UsamaAmjad I understand that, just want to configure it to work properly. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DmitryTkachev did you set `id` in your `Rule` object before executing save?

Comment: @UsamaAmjad yes, id is set

Comment: `Column 'rule_id' cannot be null` your exception saying something else

Comment: But it seems id is set, this is rules array inside Label (omit some nested fields to fit comment length):
[
  {
    "rule": {
      "name": null,
      "id": 2,
      "content": null,
      "labels": []
    },
    "label": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ooooooooooo23123123",
      "rules": [
        {
          "rule": {
            "name": null,
            "id": 2,
            "content": null,
            "labels": []
          },
          "label": 2
        }
      ],
      "parentLabel": 1
    }
  }
]

Comment: you should Edit your question description with updated error and code

Comment: I added new information in 'Update' section, is it ok?

Comment: @UsamaAmjad sorry, didn't get which query you are talking about. I just pass my object to JpaRepository.save method